# Analyzing repeated measures with a counterbalanced design in R

Tags: r, statistics, lme4

I am feeling a bit lost in analyzing my counterbalanced within-subject experimental data and I need to know if I am on the right track.

I ran a small pilot study where I randomly assigned participants to 4 counterbalanced conditions because I had 4 levels in a within-subject factor. So the four counterbalanced conditions were: ABCD, BCDA, CDAB, DABC. I am aware that I should've used a balanced Latin sq design as opposed to this cyclic design, so I want to control for the counterbalance condition itself.

Also, there were participants who didn't pass the attention/manipulation checks. So I ended up with the following distributions in each counterbalance condition: 32, 34, 38, 33.

I read some articles and discussions here in regard to the use of the mixed-effects model as opposed to the traditional repeated measures ANOVA. **My first question is:** does using the mixed-model approach make sense here given that a) people have been exposed to the counterbalance levels in an unbalanced way, and b) the assumption of sphericity has been violated when I tested using `Anova` in `car`package?

Assuming that it's ok to use the mixed-model approach, I ran the following code in R, using both `lmer` and `lme`. Condition is a within-subject factor with 4 levels, and I also have other control variables I want to account for.

`mixed_m1 <- lmer(Value ~  WorkExp + LdrspExp + WorkEnv + Age + Gender + Degree + counterbalance + Condition + (1|workerId/Condition), data=data)`

`mixed_m2 <- lme(Value~ WorkExp + LdrspExp + WorkEnv + Age + Gender + Degree + counterbalance + Condition ,random=~1|workerId/Condition,data=data, na.action=na.exclude)`

It seems the results from both approaches are almost identical, so **my second question** is: is it safe to use the output from `lme` since it gives p-values? Any caveats when using p-values from `lme`? Here is the output just in case.

```
> summary(mixed_m2)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: vigdf_long 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  1144.038 1212.434 -556.0191

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | workerId
        (Intercept)
StdDev:   0.3904907

 Formula: ~1 | Condition %in% workerId
        (Intercept)  Residual
StdDev:   0.5448806 0.2139352

Fixed effects: Value ~ WorkExp + LdrspExp + WorkEnv + Age + Gender + Degree +      counterbalance + Condition 
                                Value Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)                  4.071391 0.3395443 393 11.990751  0.0000
WorkExp                     -0.099979 0.0420833  10 -2.375734  0.0389
LdrspExp                     0.012926 0.0384698  10  0.336010  0.7438
WorkEnv                      0.042671 0.0611359  10  0.697973  0.5011
Age                         -0.012406 0.0345271 128 -0.359317  0.7200
Gender2                      0.033598 0.0989828 128  0.339430  0.7348
Degree                      -0.015818 0.0450609 128 -0.351029  0.7261
counterbalance2              0.151215 0.1078256  10  1.402403  0.1911
counterbalance3              0.058832 0.1016497  10  0.578769  0.5755
counterbalance4              0.235995 0.0827976  10  2.850268  0.0172
ConditionVig_Exploit.Explor  0.153707 0.0719766 393  2.135515  0.0333
ConditionVig_Explor.Exploit -0.117260 0.0719766 393 -1.629145  0.1041
ConditionVig_Explor.Explor   0.300035 0.0719766 393  4.168509  0.0000
 Correlation: 
                            (Intr) WrkExp LdrspE WrkEnv Age    Gendr2 Degree cntrb2 cntrb3 cntrb4 CndtnVg_Explt.E CndtnVg_Explr.Explt
WorkExp                     -0.483                                                                                                   
LdrspExp                     0.319 -0.364                                                                                            
WorkEnv                     -0.616  0.238 -0.365                                                                                     
Age                         -0.120 -0.385 -0.204  0.157                                                                              
Gender2                     -0.052 -0.205 -0.052 -0.086 -0.029                                                                       
Degree                      -0.553  0.210 -0.181 -0.172 -0.105  0.194                                                                
counterbalance2             -0.156  0.106 -0.185  0.000 -0.107  0.001  0.076                                                         
counterbalance3             -0.156  0.042 -0.286  0.019 -0.025  0.110  0.081  0.619                                                  
counterbalance4             -0.268  0.064 -0.021  0.257 -0.013 -0.053 -0.071  0.399  0.463                                           
ConditionVig_Exploit.Explor -0.106  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000                                    
ConditionVig_Explor.Exploit -0.106  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.500                             
ConditionVig_Explor.Explor  -0.106  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.500           0.500             

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-1.87767689 -0.19468774  0.03159778  0.21802779  1.88190837 

Number of Observations: 544
Number of Groups: 
               workerId Condition %in% workerId 
                    132                     528
```